# How to validate automatically String/Unicode columns maximum length when specified on declaration?

Tags: python, validation, sqlalchemy, maxlength

SQLAlchemy allows to specify a length when declaring `String` columns:

```py
foo = Column(String(10))
```

as in SQL:

```sql
foo VARCHAR(10)
```

I know this length value is used by some DBMS to allocate memory when creating a row in a table. But some DBMS (like SQLite) do not take care of it and accept this syntax only for compatibility with SQL standard. But some DBMS (like MySQL) require it to be specified.

Personally, I like to specify a maximum length for some text data because it helps to design UIs as you know the area needed to display it.

Moreover, I think it will make my application behavior more consistent across the different DBMS.

So, I want to validate the value of String/Unicode columns on insertion by **checking its length against the declared one** (when length as been declared).

### CheckConstraint

The first solution is to use a [check constraint](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/constraints.html#check-constraint):

```py
from sqlalchemy import CheckConstraint, Column, Integer, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:", echo=True)
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Foo"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bar = Column(String(10), CheckConstraint("LENGTH(bar) < 10"))


Base.metadata.create_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    session = Session()
    session.add(Foo(bar="a" * 20))

    try:
        session.commit()
    except IntegrityError as e:
        print(f"Failed with: {e.orig}")
```

It works but the SQL **constraint expression is not generated by SQLAlchemy**. So it may require some custom generation if a DBMS needs a different syntax.

### Validator

I also tried to use an SQLAlchemy [validator](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_attributes.html#simple-validators):

```py
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Foo"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bar = Column(String(10))

    @validates("bar")
    def check_bar_length(self, key, value):
        column_type = getattr(type(self), key).expression.type
        max_length = column_type.length

        if len(value) > max_length:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Value '{value}' for column '{key}' "
                f"exceed maximum length of '{max_length}'"
            )

        return value
```

```py
try:
    Foo(bar="a" * 20)
except ValueError as e:
    print(f"Failed with: {e}")
```

Now, the maximum length is inferred from the declared one.

The check is done on entity creation, not on commit. I don't know if it can be a problem.

### Custom type

**Both solutions shown above need to apply the validation on each column**. I'm looking for a solution to perform automatically the check on String/Unicode columns having a declared length.

Using a [custom type](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/custom_types.html#augmenting-existing-types) might be the solution. But it looks like a ugly hack as custom types are not made for data validation but for data transformation.

So, do you think about another solution, maybe an SQLAlchemy feature I don't know about, which will help me to add the check automatically to all `String` columns where a `length` is specified ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _but the SQL constraint expression is not generated by SQLAlchemy_.  It seems like the check constraint is generated during `Base.metadata.create_all()` and it works as intended by throwing an exception when I run your code.

Comment: @IanWilson My examples work fine. The point is that the constraint must be added manually to each column.

Comment: @IanWilson When I written that the SQL constraint expression is not **generated** by SQLAlchemy, I mean that I need to write it as a string. Only the `CHECK` keyword is generated by SA as part of the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: alright, I see what you mean, I added an answer that might be a compromise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution which seems to fit my needs.But I think the way I add the constraint is a bit hacky.

It involves the usage of:

- a [check constraint](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/constraints.html#check-constraint),
- [event listening](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/event.html).

## Entity declaration

The entity is declared as usual without the need to specify any constraint:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, LargeBinary, String, Unicode, 

class Foo(Entity):
    __tablename__ = "Foo"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    string_without_length = Column(String())
    string_with_length = Column(String(10))
    unicode_with_length = Column(Unicode(20))
    binary = Column(LargeBinary(256))
```

## Constraint attaching

The constraint is attached to the columns before the class is instrumented:

```py
from sqlalchemy import CheckConstraint, func, String
from sqlalchemy.event import listen_for
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper

@listens_for(mapper, "instrument_class")
def add_string_length_constraint(mapper, cls):
    table = cls.__table__

    for column in table.columns:
        if isinstance(column.type, String):
            length = column.type.length

            if length is not None:
                CheckConstraint(
                    func.length(column) <= length,
                    table=column,
                    _autoattach=False,
                )
```

### Resulting DDL statement (SQLite)

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Foo" (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    string_without_length VARCHAR, 
    string_with_length VARCHAR(10) CHECK (length(string_with_length) <= 10), 
    unicode_with_length VARCHAR(20) CHECK (length(unicode_with_length) <= 20), 
    binary BLOB, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

- `String` columns without length are not affected,
- `String` and `Unicode` columns with a length have a CHECK constraint added,
- other columns accepting a `length` parameter (like LargeBinary) are not affected.

### Implementation Details

```py
@listens_for(mapper, "instrument_class")
```

The `instrument_class` event occurs when the mapper for an instrumented class is created but not fully initialized. It can be listened on your base declarative class (created with `declarative_base()`) or directly on the `slqalchemy.orm.mapper` class.

```py
if isinstance(column.type, String):
```

Only `String` (and subclasses like `Unicode`) columns...

```py
if length is not None:
```

...whose `length` is set are considered.

```py
CheckConstraint(
    func.length(column) <= length,
    table=column,
    _autoattach=False,
)
```

The constraint is generated using SQLAlchemy expressions.

Finally, the **hacky part**:

When creating the constraint, SQLAlchemy automatically attach it to the table (I think it detects the column concerned by the constraint).

As I want it to be generated as part of the column definition, I disable this auto-attachement using `_autoattach=False`, then I specify the column using `table=column`.

If you don't care about it, just ignore those arguments:

```py
CheckConstraint(func.length(column) <= length)
```

The resulting DDL statement will be:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Foo" (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    string_without_length VARCHAR, 
    string_with_length VARCHAR(10), 
    unicode_with_length VARCHAR(20), 
    binary BLOB, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    CHECK (length(string_with_length) <= 10), 
    CHECK (length(unicode_with_length) <= 20)
)
```

Comment: I've been using this solution with a high degree of success.

Answer (score 2):

Another option might be to explicitly define the table and factor out your string column definitions so the check constraint is made for every string column without needing to repeat it.

```
def string_column(name, length):
    check_str = "LENGTH({}) < {}".format(name, length)
    return Column(name, String(length), CheckConstraint(check_str))


class Foo(Base):
    __table__ = Table("Foo", Base.metadata,
        Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
        string_column("bar", 10),
        string_column("name", 15))
```

Comment: It's a simple solution often used. I didn't think about it even though I already used it to define a common type for primary and foreign keys.

Comment: Please check my own answer and feel free to suggest another solution or to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to have the check done by the DB engine because when it happens the damage is done and I get an OperationalError. I think it's better to do the check before the INSERT, somehow mitigate the damage and print a log message so that I can fix the actual error in the application right where it happens. Below is what I've come up with (I recently migrated from a DB that silently truncated strings to one that threw errors when the string was too long):

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, CHAR, String, event
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    s1 = Column(String(5))
    s2 = Column(CHAR(5))

def add_string_truncaters(base):

    def add_listener(column, length):
        @event.listens_for(column, 'set', retval=True)
        def truncate(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
            if len(value) > length:
                print(f'Truncated {column}')
            return value[:length]

    for cls in globals().values():
        if (not isinstance(cls, type)
                or cls is base
                or not issubclass(cls, base)):
            continue
        for colname in cls.__table__.columns.keys():
            col = getattr(cls, colname, None)
            if col and isinstance(col.type, String):
                add_listener(col, col.type.length)

add_string_truncaters(Base)

x = Foo(s1='abcdefgh', s2='abcdefgh')
print(x.s1, x.s2)
```

It doesn't look pretty, but it seems to be sound.